Every integer $n > 1$ has a multiple less than $n^4$ whose decimal expansion has at most four distinct digits
Prove that every integer $n > 1$ has a multiple less than $n^4$ whose decimal expansion has at most four distinct digits.
Proof：Choose $k$ such that $ 2^ {k-1} $$ \leqslant $ n < $ 2^ {k} $ .The result is easy to check when
$k  \leqslant 5 $. So assume
that $k  \geqslant  6$. There are $ 2^ {k} $ > n nonnegative numbers less than $10^k$ and having only digits $0$ and $1$. Two of them must give the same remainder when divided by $n$, hence their difference
is a number with digits $0,1,8$ or $9$, which is less than $10^k < 16^{k-1} \leqslant  n^4 $.
(the inequality $10^k < 16^{k-1}$ is equivalent to $1.6^k>16$ and holds since $1.6^6>16$ and $k  \geqslant  6$)
From Number Theory: Concepts And Problems by Titu Andreescu exercise 2.93
My question: How $10^k$ comes and how the inequality $10^k < 16^{k-1}$ is equivalent to $1.6^k>16$ for $k  \geqslant  6$? Can anyone explain this proof further?
Thanks in advance.

$$10^k< 16^{k-1} $$ is equal to
$$10^{k} < \frac{16^{k}}{16}$$
Dividing by $10^{k}$ and multiplying by 16 gives
$$16 < \frac{16^{k}}{10^{k}}$$
or
$$16 < 1.6^{k}$$
This is only true for $k>6$ (just put in the numbers).
I hope that helps :)

Thanks,It’s a stupid question,l should think more carefully before post.

If you now think the question was to easy to ask, it just shows how well you understood it, so I take that as a compliment :D
